# opencv FAST corner detection algorithm

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am using opencv FAST corner detection algorithm

but I have a question about the threshold in this code

```
fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector_create(threshold=25)
```

what is the meaning of the threshold ? why we use it ?

according to [opencv](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_fast/py_fast.html) we just select an appropriate value of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the second page of [Rosten E., Drummond T. (2006). *Machine learning for high-speed corner detection*](https://www.edwardrosten.com/work/rosten_2006_machine.pdf):

> The majority of feature detection algorithms work by computing a
>   corner response function (C) across the image. **Pixels which exceed a
>   threshold cornerness value (and are locally maximal) are then
>   retained.**

and from page 5:

> The segment test criterion operates by considering a circle of sixteen
>   pixels around the corner candidate p. The original detector [2,3]
>   classifies p as a corner if there exists a set of n contiguous pixels
>   in the circle which are all brighter than the intensity of the
>   candidate pixel Ip plus a threshold t, or all darker than Ip − t, as
>   illustrated in Figure 1. n was chosen to be twelve because it admits a
>   high-speed test which can be used to exclude a very large number of
>   non-corners: the test examines only the four pixels at 1, 5, 9 and 13
>   (the four compass directions). If p is a corner then at least three of
>   these must all be brighter than Ip + t or darker than Ip − t. If
>   neither of these is the case, then p cannot be a corner. The full
>   segment test criterion can then be applied to the remaining candidates
>   by examining all pixels in the circle.

I'd recommend experimenting with different values and seeing what varying threshold changes in the output as the good way to understand the meaning/value of the threshold.